How to make TCPDF fit content from PhpSpreadsheet
I need to fill the existing Excel sheet regularly and export it to PDF. But I can't do it so that the content fits the page.
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load(Storage::path('Time&Attendance Template.xltx'));
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$pdfWriter = new Tcpdf($spreadsheet);

$sheet->getCell('A1')->setValue(Str::random());
$pdfWriter->setPaperSize(PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
$pdfWriter->setOrientation(PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$pdfWriter->save($file = Storage::path('test.pdf'));

Result:

The same file in Excel online without any scaling settings fits on one PDF page:

PS. I tried mpdf and dompdf generators. They get lines of fonts so wrong, not close enough to the original for me.
Also I don't get why vertical align doesn't work. TCPDF seems to be ignoring vertical align of the cell.

You might want to change cell width and height manually to fit the page (eg. $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);) together with font-size to imitate some sort of scale option. Another idea would be to somehow export spreadsheet to image and let TCPDF scale it for you.

Which versions of TCPDF and PhpSpreadsheet are you using?

Ok, I have faced the same problem in my project. I have exported the pdf where each record has 30 fields. I have never used TCPDF but you mentioned you tried dompdf so what I suggest is, if you use dompdf you can give css.
If you are using HTML table then try to reduce the font size of tr,td,th.
<style>
     tr,
     td,
     th {

          font-size: 10px;

     }
</style>



Manually adjust cell and font sizes:
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);

Wrap text in cells:
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);


This should solve your problem

You need to work on three things to fit the content into a single page:

Setup the Print Area
Scale the Content/Sheet
Adjust Margins and Orientation

You need to include this line which allows you to export the spreadsheet to a PDF using the Mpdf engine
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Tcpdf as PdfWriter;

Here is the updated code:
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load(Storage::path('Time&Attendance Template.xltx'));
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getCell('A1')->setValue(Str::random());

// Set the print area
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('A1:Z50'); // Adjust this range as needed

// Fit to one page
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(1);

// Set paper size and orientation
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

// Set margins if needed
$sheet->getPageMargins()->setTop(0.5);
$sheet->getPageMargins()->setRight(0.5);
$sheet->getPageMargins()->setLeft(0.5);
$sheet->getPageMargins()->setBottom(0.5);

// Export to PDF using TCPDF
$pdfWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Pdf');
$pdfWriter->save($file = Storage::path('test.pdf'));



The question explicitly asks for TCPDF, not mPDF.

@Olivier I have updated the code to use TCPDF and not mPDF
